# ¿Debemos mantener fijada la respuesta aceptada?

Tags: discusión

Muchas gracias a [@Pikoh](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/15301/pikoh) por la traducción.

---

Hace algún tiempo [cambiamos la forma de ordenar las respuestas en Stack Overflow en inglés](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/411352/). Por defecto, las respuestas se ordenan ahora estrictamente por votos (en orden descendente según la puntuación más alta), y el orden de las respuestas aceptadas en la lista se basa en su puntuación. Esta [idea ha sido discutida desde 2013](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326095/please-unpin-the-accepted-answer-from-the-top) y ahora tiene una implementación.

[Hoy podemos elegir](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/369568/274323) si queremos ver las respuestas ordenadas por su puntuación independientemente de si han sido aceptadas en Stack Overflow en español.

Tomemos una decisión juntos. ¡Por favor, compartid vuestras opiniones!

---

**Actualizar**

En base a esta discusión, desanimé la respuesta aceptada, ahora todas las respuestas están ordenadas por votos.

Comment: I'm in for this change. Accepted answer represents what helped the op, but votes represent what answer the community think it's better for everyone. Also, votes can extend in time, but accepted answers usually just reflects one moment in time.

Comment: BTW Nicolas..are you going to update [this table](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369914/346768) with our community or do you want me to do it?

Comment: @Pikoh Good catch! Done! :)

Comment: no le veo relevancia, si existen filtrados: mas recientes, mas populares(mas votos), resueltas, etc, que sea el usuario en su configuracion de perfil o en el view de resultafo que decida cual sera su filtro por defecto.

Comment: ¿Cómo se vota esta propuesta?

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo con Arcanis. Para que implementar algo así si ya se puede hacer ordenando por mas populares? Y me surgió la misma duda que Candid Moe. Como voto?

Comment: Si de todos modos esto se implementa, les pediría el favor de que haya una forma de hayar rapidamente la respuesta aceptada.

Comment: @DanteS. Muestrame una imagen en donde ordenas por populares las respuestas de una pregunta pls.

Comment: @excorpion Espera, incluso ordenada parece que la respuesta aceptada está arriba de todo.

Answer (score 19):

Que el OP haya aceptado una respuesta no es garantía de nada. Puede que le sirva, pero eso no la hace una buena respuesta.

Puede que simplemente haya aceptado la primera respuesta, sin esperar a ver alternativas mejores.

El OP es en general un programador poco experimentado, mientras que quienes votan son personas más dedicadas y experimentadas. Está claro que sus opiniones pesan más.

En resumen doy más credibilidad a los votos como medida de la excelencia de las respuestas.

Mi respuesta a la pregunta *¿Debemos mantener fijada la respuesta aceptada?* es No.

Comment: esto no es del todo cierto ... ***quienes votan son personas más dedicadas y experimentadas***

Comment: pero en general estoy de acuerdo ...

Answer (score 10):

La respuesta correcta no tiene por qué ser la aceptada ni la de más votos. Se que esta frase puede tirar por tierra toda la filosofía de StackExchange pero es así: cualquier sistema basado en humanos contiene herror umano.

Así que, teniendo en cuenta que ambas opciones<sup>1</sup> son malas se debería optar por el mal menor, que en mi opinión es ordenar por votos.

---

<sup>1</sup>Opción A: Ordenar por votos. Opción B: Ordenar por aceptada.

Comment: me gustaría ver algunos ejemplos, pero estoy totalmente de acuerdo

Comment: @RuslanLópez [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/499359) tienes un ejemplo de respuesta aceptada y respuesta con más votos que ni es la mejor respuesta ni soluciona el problema... por brillante que sea.

Comment: no tiene sentido ordenar por aceptada por que solo se puede aceptar una respuesta por pregunta...

Comment: @Arcanis-TheOmnipotent "Ordenar por aceptada" se refiere a poner la respuesta aceptada primera, independientemente de la cantidad de votos que tenga.

Comment: ESO no es **Ordenar por Aceptada** cuando usas el termino ordenar es por que tienes un grupo de cosas con el mismo estatus que puede organizar...
si se pueden aceptar 2 preguntas te creería; lo que estas diciendo es Fijar la Pregunta Aceptada (no ordenar).

Comment: @Arcanis-TheOmnipotent efectivamente. Tienes un grupo de cosas con el mismo estatus: aceptación (y su ausencia). Ergo, puedes ordenar por ese criterio. Y si lees mi respuesta, estoy diciendo lo contrario a "*Fijar la Pregunta Aceptada*".

Comment: pierde sentido cuando solo puede haber una respuesta marcada como aceptada dentro de un cumulo de respuestas... la pregunta aceptada puedes fijarla al inicio o al final mediante el criterio de aceptada  ya que ese es el único que la diferencia de las otras respuesta ... si las ordenas por voto esa pregunta puede aparecer en cualquier lugar ...

Comment: cuando hablas del estatus de **Aceptada** no puede decir que vas a ordenar ... ya que la pregunta aceptada es única en un post... el termino correcto es Fijar la respuesta marcada como aceptada en algún lugar si es que así deseas emplearla... si el criterio que vas a usar es el ordenamiento por voto entonces deberías ignorar el hecho de que este aceptada o no .... a menos que quieras dar una respuesta hibrida como la mía, pero utilizando tus criterios: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5328/46896

Comment: @Arcanis-TheOmnipotent ¿Estamos discutiendo nomenclatura? Porque sinceramente, me da igual llamarlo "Fijar respuestas" que "Ordenar por aceptada"... aparentemente usar una u otra nomenclatura te parece de una importancia vital pero, tranqui, no es para tanto.

Comment: Si claro este POST fue marcado como discusión me parece importante discutir, definir y compartir conceptos y definiciones, lo ideal es que todos hablen el mismo idioma XD

Comment: Pues nada, tu ganas, "Ordenar por Aceptada" (es decir: usar el criterio de aceptada/no-aceptada como criterio para ordenar) lo llamaré "Fijar respuesta" (es decir: poner la respuesta aceptada primero).

Answer (score 5):

**UNPIN LA RESPUESTA ACEPTADA // UNPIN THE ACCEPTED ASNWER**

La respuesta aceptada, no siempre es la correcta, la más indicada, o la óptima.
Por esto es que el sistema de votos existe, para que la comunidad apoye lo útil, y deseche lo que en realidad no sirve. Hasta el día de hoy existen respuestas aceptadas sin votos, o en negativo, lo que demuestra que no son la real solución, solo fueron las más rápidas en el momento, o la que le funcionó al OP.

Por otro lado, la respuesta aceptada, no perderá su estado de aceptada, y que haya funcionado en su momento.

---

The accepted answer in not always the correct one, the most indicated, or the optimal.
This is why we have a vote system, so the community can support the usefull answers over the other ones. To this day, there are answers without upvotes, or with downvotes, so that shows that they arent the real solution, they just where faster at the moment, or what worked for the OP at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

Una respuesta aceptada obedece al criterio de una sola persona, los votos obedecen al criterio de (potencialmente) mas de una.

Como ya dijeron, lo que en general indica la respuesta aceptada es la resolución del problema concreto del OP, los votos suelen indicar una solución mas general.

Pero otro tema muy importante, según mi opinión, es que las respuestas aceptadas, además de obedecer al criterio del problema concreto, obedecen al criterio que existe en un momento determinado. Toda vez que existan cambios en la tecnología (cambios de versiones, nuevas vulnerabilidades, etc), los votos (lentamente) van acompañando de alguna manera ese cambio, pero las respuestas aceptadas muy rara vez cambian el status de "aceptada", porque al OP le fue resuelto su problema específico en un momento específico y eso no cambió.

El valor que agrega ver en primer lugar una solución posiblemente deprecada, que obedece al juicio de una sola persona, en mi opinión no se justifica.

Por todo lo dicho, opino que **no** se debería mantener fijada la respuesta aceptada.

Answer (score 0):

**Personalmente considero que se deberia tomar en cuenta los siguientes conceptos:**

1. las pregungas solo pueden tener una respuesta marcada como la que resuelve el problema, sea o no sea la mejor.
2. las respuestas marcadas con recomensas sean o no la que responde la pregunta se suponen que son las de mejor calidad.
3. tenemos las respuetas con votos positivos pero que no fueron seleccionadas como respuestas.
4. tenemos las respuesta con votos negativos.

Basado en estos conceptos personalmente puedo argumentar que, el orden que he descrito es el que mejor plantea las respuesta para la comunidad agregando que las respuesta con más de N cantidades de votos negativos deberian ser ocultadas/ofuscadas quedando asi:

1. marcada como respuesta.
2. ganadoras de recompenza.
3. por votos positivos de mayor a menor.
4. por votos negativo de menor a mayor.
5. ocultada/ofuscadas con mas de 7 votos negativos.

**¿Porque creo que debe de ser asi?**

Por que a la comunidad le interesa mejorar la respuesta que fue marcada como la que resuelve el problema y normalmente, en la busqueda de duplicados buscamos una que haya sido marcada como la que resuelve, para afirmar que es el camino correcto para la resolucion de un problema.

**Problemas con el versionado**

No podemos esperar que una sola respuesta o pregunta, encuentre la respuesta para todas las versiones. agradeceria a la comunidad tomar muy en cuenta este dato antes de marcar una pregunta como duplicada. ya que una respuesta para un scenario especifico de una version vieja de pyhton, no necesriamente es la mejor respuesta para una nueva pregunta basada en una version nueva.

Personalmente concidero que estas preguntas deben mantenerce por separado. y no ser marcadas como duplicadas.

tambien concidero que agregar respuesta basadas en una version nueva a una pregunta basada en una version vieja, tampoco es correcto... si bien es cierto que esto soluciona algun problema a la comunidad, no ayuda en nada al usuario que ha escenificado su pregunta en una version en concreto.

Esto personalmente me molesta, por que si estoy desarrollando un ERP o un ORM y para resolver un problema me piden que primero migre todo el proyecto, por que tu respuesta esta basada en una version nueva del lenguaje... tu respuesta cae en un concepto de **inviabilidad** que no resuelve el problema...

Answer (score -2):

Por mi parte creo que la mejor opción es mantener fijada la respuesta aceptada como se ha hecho hasta ahora, si bien no siempre es la más precisa, es la que ha ayudado al OP, que es quien ha expuesto el problema, por lo que aun sin ser la mejor, en la mayoría de casos es una solución.

**Como comenta** @CandidMoe **en su respuesta**:

> El OP es en general un programador poco experimentado, mientras que quienes votan son personas más dedicadas y experimentadas. Está claro que sus opiniones pesan más.

Esto puede ser cierto o no, pero sin duda, las otras personas no han tenido que lidiar directamente con ese problema y en algunos casos creo que se puede estar priorizando la calidad de una respuesta frente a la solución de un problema.

**Respondiendo a** @PaperBirdMaster:

> Así que, teniendo en cuenta que ambas opciones1 son malas se debería optar por el mal menor, que en mi opinión es ordenar por votos.

En la mayoría de casos la solución al problema del OP es la que indica la respuesta aceptada, por lo que si alguien se enfrenta al mismo problema, la respuesta aceptada puede tener más opciones.

En mi experiencia he visto varias respuestas con más votos que la aceptada por el OP en las que se evalúa la calidad de la respuesta sobre la solución, donde se tiende, **a veces**, a dar prioridad a otros factores independientes de la implementación de la propia solución.

**Ejemplo**: Op tiene problema X con codigo Y.

**Respuesta aceptada** (5 votos): Tienes esto mal en tu código, cámbialo.

**Respuesta no aceptada** (12 votos): Estás haciendo esto mal en tu código X, cambia la forma en la que lo haces para hacerlo así y asá. Pudiendo implicar cambios, repito, en ocasiones, sobre la pregunta original.

---

Opción B: Ordenar por aceptada.

Si bien la respuesta aceptada a veces no es la mejor, es sin duda la que mayor certeza tenemos de que ha dado al menos una solución al problema que el OP presenta, en ocasiones una respuesta mejor puede implicar cambiar el propio problema que el OP expone por diversos motivos.

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo con que en las respuestas no aceptadas, que a veces tienen mas puntos, dicen cosas del tipo "cambia la forma en la que lo haces para hacerlo así y asá", eso es justamente un argumento en contra del pin, quizá se da el tilde a una respuesta que soluciona un problema que está mal encarado.